# sql query count number of record in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have to extract the list of POS(point of service) from pos table, based on location name:

```
POS
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country  | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

so, it would be something like :

```
select *
from pos
where location = 'new york';
```

Now , from the table mission i have to count the number of POS (pos_name), and if this number is greater than a number coming from a subquery, pos register should not be shown.

mission

```
| id                      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| team_name               | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| team_photo              | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| pos_name                | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| pos_id                  | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| product_category        | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| product_platform        | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_by              | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| judged_by               | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| selfie_photo            | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| like_score              | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| star_score              | float         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| feedback_recommendation | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at              | timestamp     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at              | timestamp     | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| sent_date               | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| locked                  | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

so until now i developed following sql query :

```
SELECT p.id,p.name 
FROM missions m join pos p
on m.pos_id = p.id
where p.location = 'new york'
having count(m.pos_name) < (select count(*)
                          from product_category);
```

but this part of code

```
having count(m.pos_name)
```

should be something like that :

```
select count(*) 
from missions 
group by pos_name;
```

because without group by statement i will recieve a sum of all pos, but i need to check it for a group, not for all of them.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried `having count(distinct m.pos_name)`?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need the data with group by with condition then try this

```
SELECT p.id,p.name 
FROM missions m join pos p
on m.pos_id = p.id
where p.location = 'new york'
group by m.pos_name
having count(m.pos_name) < (select count(*)
                      from product_category);
```

Just add `group by m.pos_name` it will work.
You can check [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)